# Joomla 1.5 site keeps getting blocked by host

Tags: joomla, firewall, brute-force, blocked

I have a Joomla 1.5.26 site which I have had since Aug 2012. It has been in a stable condition since Aug, with no changes to components etc. It is firewalled with RS Firewall and all the other security precautions have been taken.

During the past few weeks the site has started to be blocked by the hosting company that holds the site, who claim that there are too many active connections. I have hunted through the sites, disabled various components etc and am still getting the same problems.

Has anyone experienced any similar issues? I am thinking of moving the site to a more reputable host for Joomla sites to see if it is more robust elsehwere. I just can't undertand why this keeps happening. The Hosts, are placing the IP address of any machines we use to administer the site if the connections get too many, and then we are locked out for about fifteen minutes. As I said previously, nothing has changed on the site, and I cannot find any evidence of the files or database being hacked.

Any ideas?

Much appreciated

James

Answer (score 0):

If your host is telling you that there have been too many connection then it will most likely mean 1 of the following 3:

1. You site has reached the maximum monthly bandwidth allowance
2. Your site has too much traffic for your current host and might need to be moved to a VPS server or something more powerful
3. You host is plain crap

Check to if you have reached your maximum monthly bandwidth allowance (if you have one) else I would probably recommend transferring to a different host, if you site isn't an extremely popular site, generating thousands of users a day.